# PHP - save as file (excel)

Tags: php, excel, mysqli

i have a working download file of excel but first i want to put a download window popping up.now, it will just automatically generate without save file window. how can i do that. please help me.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script language="javascript">
    function download()
    {
        window.location='report.xls';
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body alink="#00FF66" link="#00CC00">
    <h1 align="center"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="download();">Download Excel Report</a></h1>
    <?php

    require_once("db.php");
    require_once("excelwriter.class.php");

    $excel=new ExcelWriter("report.xls");
    if($excel==false)   
    echo $excel->error;

    $myArr=array("Model","Code","Desc","Stock Requested","Stock Received", "Diff", "On hand");
    $excel->writeLine($myArr);

    $sql="SELECT allinvty3.*, barcode.* ,  sample.*, count(barcode.itemcode) as icount  from barcode 
         INNER JOIN sample on barcode.itemcode = sample.in_code    
         INNER JOIN allinvty3 on barcode.itemcode = allinvty3.in_code 
      group by  barcode.itemcode";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);


    if($sql!=false)
    {
        $i=1;

     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
$myArr=array($row['ecr_desc'],$row['itemcode'],
$row['ite_desc'],$row['tqty'],$row['icount'], $row['icount'],
 $row['icount']);
            $excel->writeLine($myArr);
            $i++;
        }
    }

    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

excelwriter.class.php

```
<?php

     /*
     * Class is used for save the data into microsoft excel format.
     * It takes data into array or you can write data column vise.
     */


    Class ExcelWriter
    {

        var $fp=null;
        var $error;
        var $state="CLOSED";
        var $newRow=false;

        /*
        * @Params : $file  : file name of excel file to be created.
        * @Return : On Success Valid File Pointer to file
        *           On Failure return false  
        */

        function ExcelWriter($file="")
        {
            return $this->open($file);
        }


        function open($file)
        {
            if($this->state!="CLOSED")
            {
                $this->error="Error : Another file is opend .Close it to save the file";
                return false;
            }   

            if(!empty($file))
            {
                $this->fp=@fopen($file,"w+");
            }
            else
            {
                $this->error="Usage : New ExcelWriter('fileName')";
                return false;
            }   
            if($this->fp==false)
            {
                $this->error="Error: Unable to open/create File.You may not have permmsion to write the file.";
                return false;
            }
            $this->state="OPENED";
            fwrite($this->fp,$this->GetHeader());
            return $this->fp;
        }

        function close()
        {
            if($this->state!="OPENED")
            {
                $this->error="Error : Please open the file.";
                return false;
            }   
            if($this->newRow)
            {
                fwrite($this->fp,"</tr>");
                $this->newRow=false;
            }

            fwrite($this->fp,$this->GetFooter());
            fclose($this->fp);
            $this->state="CLOSED";
            return ;
        }
        /* @Params : Void
        *  @return : Void
        * This function write the header of Excel file.
        */

        function GetHeader()
        {
            $header = <<<EOH
                <html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
                xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

                <head>
                <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
                <meta name=ProgId content=Excel.Sheet>
                <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
                 <o:DocumentProperties>
                  <o:LastAuthor>Sriram</o:LastAuthor>
                  <o:LastSaved>2005-01-02T07:46:23Z</o:LastSaved>
                  <o:Version>10.2625</o:Version>
                 </o:DocumentProperties>
                 <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
                  <o:DownloadComponents/>
                 </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
                </xml><![endif]-->
                <style>
                <!--table
                    {mso-displayed-decimal-separator:"\.";
                    mso-displayed-thousand-separator:"\,";}
                @page
                    {margin:1.0in .75in 1.0in .75in;
                    mso-header-margin:.5in;
                    mso-footer-margin:.5in;}
                tr
                    {mso-height-source:auto;}
                col
                    {mso-width-source:auto;}
                br
                    {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}
                .style0
                    {mso-number-format:General;
                    text-align:general;
                    vertical-align:bottom;
                    white-space:nowrap;
                    mso-rotate:0;
                    mso-background-source:auto;
                    mso-pattern:auto;
                    color:windowtext;
                    font-size:10.0pt;
                    font-weight:400;
                    font-style:normal;
                    text-decoration:none;
                    font-family:Arial;
                    mso-generic-font-family:auto;
                    mso-font-charset:0;
                    border:none;
                    mso-protection:locked visible;
                    mso-style-name:Normal;
                    mso-style-id:0;}
                td
                    {mso-style-parent:style0;
                    padding-top:1px;
                    padding-right:1px;
                    padding-left:1px;
                    mso-ignore:padding;
                    color:windowtext;
                    font-size:10.0pt;
                    font-weight:400;
                    font-style:normal;
                    text-decoration:none;
                    font-family:Arial;
                    mso-generic-font-family:auto;
                    mso-font-charset:0;
                    mso-number-format:General;
                    text-align:general;
                    vertical-align:bottom;
                    border:none;
                    mso-background-source:auto;
                    mso-pattern:auto;
                    mso-protection:locked visible;
                    white-space:nowrap;
                    mso-rotate:0;}
                .xl24
                    {mso-style-parent:style0;
                    white-space:normal;}
                -->
                </style>
                <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
                 <x:ExcelWorkbook>
                  <x:ExcelWorksheets>
                   <x:ExcelWorksheet>
                    <x:Name>srirmam</x:Name>
                    <x:WorksheetOptions>
                     <x:Selected/>
                     <x:ProtectContents>False</x:ProtectContents>
                     <x:ProtectObjects>False</x:ProtectObjects>
                     <x:ProtectScenarios>False</x:ProtectScenarios>
                    </x:WorksheetOptions>
                   </x:ExcelWorksheet>
                  </x:ExcelWorksheets>
                  <x:WindowHeight>10005</x:WindowHeight>
                  <x:WindowWidth>10005</x:WindowWidth>
                  <x:WindowTopX>120</x:WindowTopX>
                  <x:WindowTopY>135</x:WindowTopY>
                  <x:ProtectStructure>False</x:ProtectStructure>
                  <x:ProtectWindows>False</x:ProtectWindows>
                 </x:ExcelWorkbook>
                </xml><![endif]-->
                </head>

                <body link=blue vlink=purple>
                <table x:str border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 style='border-collapse: collapse;table-layout:fixed;'>
EOH;
            return $header;
        }

        function GetFooter()
        {
            return "</table></body></html>";
        }

        /*
        * @Params : $line_arr: An valid array 
        * @Return : Void
        */

        function writeLine($line_arr)
        {
            if($this->state!="OPENED")
            {
                $this->error="Error : Please open the file.";
                return false;
            }   
            if(!is_array($line_arr))
            {
                $this->error="Error : Argument is not valid. Supply an valid Array.";
                return false;
            }
            fwrite($this->fp,"<tr>");
            foreach($line_arr as $col)
                fwrite($this->fp,"<td class=xl24 width=64 >$col</td>");
            fwrite($this->fp,"</tr>");
        }

        /*
        * @Params : Void
        * @Return : Void
        */
        function writeRow()
        {
            if($this->state!="OPENED")
            {
                $this->error="Error : Please open the file.";
                return false;
            }   
            if($this->newRow==false)
                fwrite($this->fp,"<tr>");
            else
                fwrite($this->fp,"</tr><tr>");
            $this->newRow=true; 
        }

        /*
        * @Params : $value : Coloumn Value
        * @Return : Void
        */
        function writeCol($value)
        {
            if($this->state!="OPENED")
            {
                $this->error="Error : Please open the file.";
                return false;
            }   
            fwrite($this->fp,"<td class=xl24 width=64 >$value</td>");
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: you cant tell the browser where to save a file. that wold be a huge security issue

Comment: i just have to so i can rename my excel file i mean a download window popping up.

Comment: not sure i understand the question then

Comment: i want to have a download window popping up.

Comment: that class is not actually creating an excel file, but HTML. you should use https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel